# Can i put border to a form using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this code below, and i want to add a border to make like a box using bootstrap class ".border", but i can't figure out why is not working!. Is possible using bootstrap v4?

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class=" col-sm-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: add a class `border` to `form` & provide custom css to that class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup you can put a border around your form. You can achieve that by using inline CSS as shown below :

`<form style="border:1px solid black">`

Comment: Yes! but i was thinking in using native bootstrap .border class, but i just cant figure out how to! :/

Comment: You can try **form-control** class of bootstrap.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a pretty good combination for a bordered form with background color:

```
<form class = 'card p-3 bg-light'>
```

Looked good for my case.

Comment: +1 Looks great. I used `form-container card p-3 bg-light` do you think the `form-container` part at the start is necessary? (I kept it because it's what I had before, but not sure if it serves any purpose)

Comment: There is no form-container in bootstrap, as far as I know.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a very late response, but I feel obligated to share a more "bootstrap" way of doing this. Simply use the classes `card` and `p-1` for a border and padding between your content and said border.

```
<form class = 'card p-1'>
```

Answer (score 3):

yes you can.

if you use internal style sheet

```
<head>
<style>
.border-class
{
  border:thin black solid;
  margin:20px;
  padding:20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center ">
      <form class="border-class">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class=" col-sm-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes! but i was thinking in using native bootstrap .border class, but i just cant figure out how to! :/ –

Answer (score 2):

```css
.b {
  border:thin black solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center ">
      <form class="b">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class=" col-sm-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Something like this?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! but i was thinking in using native bootstrap .border class, but i just cant figure out how to! :/

Comment: i guess there is no class called `border` in native bootstrap. so you have to write custom css for that.

Comment: I tried bootstrap form-control class ! it works as i expected :)

Answer (score 2):

add "well" tag to your outer div element

Ex : < div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 well" >

Comment: This is the most "boostrap" way of doing it.

Comment: In case you are using bootstrap 4, use "card" instead of "well"